# Why do my print jobs get executed halfway and then automatically paused?

Tags: printing, epson

I've had this issue since upgrading to 18.04 now, on both Xubuntu and regular Ubuntu, with multiple programs and it's really frustrating.

Whenever I start a print job on my printer (Epson WF-7015), it's a gamble if the document is printed or not. Sometimes, it will print without any issues, other times, the printer will halt halfway through, the print queue will show the job as "paused" and the printout has fading lines as if the ink was empty (however, it's not, this happens with new cartridges).

I can then manually delete the print job and restart it, but I've wasted a lot of high-quality paper already, not knowing if the printing will succeed or not.

Has anybody got any experience with this issue, could help with troubleshooting or offer a solution to this problem?

Here's the output of `/var/log/cups/error_log.1`, corresponding to the last unsuccessful print:

```
E [27/Jul/2019:12:23:22 +0200] [cups-deviced] PID 2386 (gutenprint52+usb) stopped with status 1!
E [27/Jul/2019:13:25:37 +0200] [Job 25] Unable to send data to printer.
E [27/Jul/2019:13:28:51 +0200] [Job 25] Unable to send data to printer.
E [27/Jul/2019:13:31:46 +0200] [Job 26] Unable to send data to printer.
E [27/Jul/2019:13:32:58 +0200] [Job 26] Unable to send data to printer.
E [27/Jul/2019:13:43:53 +0200] [Client 2774] Returning IPP client-error-not-possible for Cancel-Job (ipp://localhost/jobs/26) from localhost
E [27/Jul/2019:13:43:56 +0200] [Client 2774] Returning IPP client-error-not-possible for Cancel-Job (ipp://localhost/jobs/26) from localhost
E [27/Jul/2019:13:44:01 +0200] [Client 2774] Returning IPP client-error-not-possible for Cancel-Job (ipp://localhost/jobs/26) from localhost
E [27/Jul/2019:13:49:56 +0200] [cups-deviced] PID 4351 (gutenprint52+usb) stopped with status 1!
```

(Jobs 25 and 26 were cancelled, then everything was restarted. Job 27 (same file / settings, was successful.)

Comment: Inspect the log files in `/var/log/cups`

Comment: @waltinator, I've added the output of the error log. Thanks!

Comment: Noticed it mentions gutenprint at the bottom. Others have reported problems with this module and they also received the same errors you did. Try this: delete cups and gutenprint -- delete cups configuration directory (/etc/cups) -- reinstall cups + configure printer. Here's a link to a similar question and answer: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=208475